# UITableView, InsertRowsAtIndexPath Handling Multiple Requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a method named "fetchEntries"in my tableview controller that is putting data by fetching from the web service. It is also taking a parameter named "pageNumber" which i am incrementing by calling this method from another method. This pageNumber is actually pulling data from different pages of the rss feed.

```
- (void) fetchEntries:(NSInteger )pageNumber
{ 
        channel = [[TheFeedStore sharedStore] fetchWebService:pageNumber withCompletion:^(RSSChannel *obj, NSError *err){

            if (!err) {
                int currentItemCount = [[channel items] count];
                channel = obj;
                int newItemCount = [[channel items] count];

                int itemDelta = newItemCount - currentItemCount;

                if (itemDelta > 0) {

                    NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray array];

                    for (int i = 0; i < itemDelta; i++) {
                        NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                        [rows addObject:ip];
                    }
                    [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
                    [aiView stopAnimating];
                }
            }
        }];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];

}
```

It is working absolutely fine. The issue arises when for example the pageNumber is 1 and it is in the process of the loading data in the tableview, if the process is not yet completed since there are images involved, and i increment the pageNumber to 2, it will stop loading the entries from page 1 and starts loading page 2 without completing the page 1.

**QUESTION: 1) Is there any way i can customise so that "insertRowsAtIndexPath" method starts loading the page 2 entries starting at the index where page 1 entries finishes.
2) or, is there any way i can put them in separate threads so they can function independently and they both run concurrently.**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: make a custom UITableView and then you can override insertRowsAtIndex path if you want